# How to write a file using FileWriter to google dataproc?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a java spark application where the output from the spark job needs to be collected and then saved into a csv file. This is my code below:

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter("gs://dataflow-exp1/google_storage_tests/20170524/outputfolder/Test.csv", true);
fileWriter.append("col1,col2,col3,col4");
```

When i execute the spark job in google data proc, i get the file not found exception. Also i do have read/write permissions to that folder.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: gs:/dataflow-exp1/google_storage_tests/20170524/outputfolder/Test.csv (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:78)
at com.src.main.MyApp.testWriteOutput(MyApp.java:72)
at com.src.main.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

It looks like the filewriter at runtime uses single slash `/` instead of the double slashes `//`after `gs:`. How can i solve this?

I am also open to other ways instead of FileWriter to write a file to google data proc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dataproc installs a [Hadoop FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) connector for GCS which is accessible from Spark; in general, things in Hadoop or Spark should build on top of that interface, which is *not* automatically compatible with basic Java File interfaces. You should do something like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

Path outputPath = new Path("gs://dataflow-exp1/google_storage_tests/20170524/outputfolder/Test.csv");
OutputStream out = outputPath.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).create(outputPath);
```

And then adapt it for whatever writer interfaces you need.

Answer (score -1):

fileWriter = new FileWriter("gs:/"+"/dataflowexp1/google_storage_tests/20170524/outputfolder/Test.csv", true);
fileWriter.append("col1,col2,col3,col4");

//try this